# Generate list of remaining numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given a number n, and an array with size m where m<n. Provided that each number in the array is between 0 and n-1 (inclusive), I want to get as efficiently as possible the list of n-m numbers from 0 to n-1 which aren't in the array.

That's how I'm doing it (in pseudocode), but it feels rather inefficient and I'm wondering if there's a better way:

```
int[] remaining (int[] assigned) {
    Set<int> s
    int[n-m] remaining
    add each int in assigned to s
    for(i = 0 to n-1) 
        if(not s.contains(i)) remaining.add(i);
}
```

This isn't any particular computer language but it should be ilustrative. We'll assume that accessing an array is of course O(1) and adding/checking a set is O(log(n)) as an AVL set would be. So basically I'm trying to get this in linear time, instead of O(n·logn) like it's now, but if the initial array isn't sorted I don't know how to go about it, or if it's even possible.

Comment: If you can afford the memory, an array of bits of size n could be used to solve the problem in linear time. (The algorithm is obvious.)

Comment: I don't quite follow what's the obvious algorithm. Could you please explain?

EDIT: Oh, wait, by bit you meant boolean?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I was thinking that you would init the bit array to all 0's, go through your list of numbers setting the corresponding bit to 1, and then go through the bit array and printing the positions of all the bits that are still zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be a little faster
pseudocode also

```
int[] remaining (int[] assigned) {
    Set<int> s
    int[n] all
    int[n-m] remaining
    for(i = 0 to m-1) 
        all[assigned[i]]=-1
    int counter=0
    for(i = 0 to n-1) 
        if (all[i]==-1)
            remaining[counter]=all[i]
            counter++
    return remaining
}
```

Answer (score 3):

copy the array into a hashmap `H`. This takes `O(m)`.

```
for i from 0 to n-1
    if(H.ispresent(i) == FALSE)
        output i
```

This for loop takes `O(n)`.
As `n>=m` the overall complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: Or now that I think about it I can use an array of integers (which would be a particular implementation of a hash map with key-value pairs being int-int. Anyway, nice answer, thanks!

Comment: @Setzer22 That would be identical (in essence) to the bit array idea, except that using ints (or a hashmap) would take vastly more space.

Answer (score 2):

The bitset (bit array) idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <bitset>

const int SIZE = 10;  // for example

int main() {
    std::bitset<SIZE> bs;
    int i;

    std::ifstream fin("numbers.txt");
    while (fin >> i)
        bs.set(i);
    fin.close();

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        if (!bs[i])
            std::cout << i << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well I'm actually using Java so no luck with the STL, but I was asking for the general idea and this answers it, so thanks!. And despite this being essentially the same the bitset concept carries an ugly overhead with it as the memory of any modern computer has to be written at least byte per byte, so there's no magic bit access, it's just bitwise operations underneath it, which most people don't like.

Comment: @Setzer22 That's the tradeoff, all right. I assumed you'd have, potentially, millions (or billions) of numbers, otherwise why bother with the optimization? So memory use would be important, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to find 1 or 2 missing numbers, you can always use the sum and/or the product of the numbers to figure out the missing numbers.If it is more than 2

Code for using a Bitset in java to find the missing numbers.

```
public List<Integer> findMissingNumbers(List<Integer> input,int maxNum){
```

/*You can also interate through the list and find the maNum later. The bitset is     based on vector and can increase in size
    */
    if(input==null ||  input.size()==0)
      return null;

```
BitSet existSet=new BitSet(maxNum);
for(int val:input){
    existSet.set(val);
}

List<Integer> missingNum=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<existSet.length()){
     nextIndex=bitSet.nextClearBit();
     if(nextIndex==-1)
       break;
     missingNum.add(nextIndex);
     index=nextIndex+1;

}
return missingNum;
```

}